# Change behavior of initialize fields to create protected properties, rather than private

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Is it possible to configure phpstorm's initialize fields command to create protected properties, rather than private ones?

[image: Initialize fields]
[image: private]

Comment: This fields were generated by IntelliJ  before?

Comment: IntelliJ generates the `private queryBuilder;` part I'd prefer `protected $queryBuilder;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In PhpStorm 2017.3.2 you can change fields default visibility in the next way:
Project Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) => Editor => Code Style => PHP => Code Generation tab => Fields Default Visibility. 
Works fine for me.

Comment: Still correct in version 2018.3.4

Comment: I was able to do this before, but in PHPStorm 2020.1 that setting does not appear to have an effect on generated code.

Comment: It works on PHPStorm version 2023.1.3

Answer (score 3):

I've searched around for answer to this question.

What I've found out is that you cannot modify behavior of this function without modifying [PHP plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6610). This plugin is in fact responsible for behavior of Initialize fields function.

Here is the example of edit initialize fields option. But it's read only:

[image: PHPStorm intentions window]